# Get parameters at the end of URL on Apache Web Server

Tags: javascript, apache, webserver, url-rewriting

I have a URL with the following syntax:

```
https://www.domain.com/pay/a1b2c
```

In the `/pay` directory I have a simple payment form. I am using JavaScript to get the URL appendix `a1b2c` and process it in order to get further data to display in the payment form:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var appendix = url.split("/").pop();
...
```

But if I open the URL in the browser, Apache says (of course):

```
Not Found
The requested URL /pay/a1b2c was not found on this server.
```

How can I solve this problem? Which Apache config do I need?

Comment: Take a look at the rewriting module apache offers for this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html You will find literally millions of examples for this here on SO and on google.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for the hint. But do you know how to implement this? I am still confused about the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by asking humbedoo on the Apache Mailing list:

You can use [AcceptPathInfo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html) in order to get the appendix.

> For example, assume the location /test/ points to a directory that
>   contains only the single file here.html. Then requests for
>   /test/here.html/more and /test/nothere.html/more both collect /more as
>   PATH_INFO.